# Protecting constants

Tags: android, constants

I am using some constants using public static final statement. But it can be visible if the apk is reverse engineered. Is there any solution to restrict constants from visibility?

Answer (score 0):

Anything can be reverse-engineered. In your case it's only way to use proguard.

Comment: But it will not restrict from showing what constant is apk using

Comment: it will hide the name of variables

Comment: Нou also can make static native method but hackers will solve it by replacing this method with constant.

Comment: For example, usually we maintain Database table names in constants. In order to restrict it from knowing

Comment: You can only confuse hackers and make some difficult logic in your code to protect it from reverse-engeneering.

Comment: Is it ok to maintain constants in the string. xml resource?

Comment: Yes you can do this, nice hack :)

Comment: Nice hack to make them visible by simply extracting the xml with a zip decruncher.